# Leer 100 caracteres de un texto

Tags: c#, c, string

necesito encontrar una forma de leer los caracteres de un texto de 100 en 100. Puedo leer los primeros 100, pero no encuentro la manera de iniciar el segundo ciclo. Aparte de eso, igual tengo que guardar las palabras que terminen con ing de texto. Para identificar las palabras con ing ya lo tengo, pero no encuentro la manera de guardarlas para después imprimirlas. Espero puedan ayudarme, estoy haciendo el programa en lenguaje C.

Esta es una parte del código:

```
void lecturaArchivo(){

char caracteres[100];
char *ap = &caracteres[0];

int  n = 100;

FILE* archivo;
archivo = fopen("Archivo.txt","rt");

do{
    fgets(caracteres,n,archivo);

    for (; *ap!='\0' || *ap!=EOF ;ap++)
    {
        if(*ap=='i' && estado == 0){
                pos++;
                fprintf(salida,"Estado:%i\nLetra: %c\n\n",estado,*ap);
                impresion(ap, estado);
                estado = 1;
        }else{
            if(*ap=='n' && estado == 1){
                pos++;
                fprintf(salida,"Estado:%i\nLetra: %c\n\n",estado,*ap);
                impresion(ap, estado);
                estado = 2;

            }else{
                if(*ap=='g' && estado == 2 && *ap+1 == ' '){
                    pos++; 
                    fprintf(salida,"Estado:%i\nLetra: %c\n\n",estado,*ap);
                    impresion(ap, estado);

                }else{
                        if(*ap == ' '){
                            pos++;
                            posiciones[pos] = pos;
                            fprintf(salida,"Estado:%i\nLetra: %c\n\n",estado,*ap);
                            impresion(ap, estado);
                            estado = 0;
                        } else{
                            pos++;
                            fprintf(salida,"Estado:%i\nLetra: %c\n\n",estado,*ap);
                            impresion(ap, estado);
                            estado = 0;
                        }


                }

            }
        }

    }

    n = 200;

} while(*ap!='\0' || *ap!=EOF);
```

}

Comment: Es una pregunta muy escueta con falta de información. Para seguir el segundo ciclo debes tener una condición lógica que diga cuando debe parar de leer. Además deberías adjuntar el código de lo que tengas para poder ayudarte

Comment: Hola Enrique, ¿Has investigado o intentado algo? ¿Podrías poner tu código? Si el programa lo haces en C, ¿cuál sería la razón de agregar la etiqueta [tag:C#]?

Comment: Una forma sencilla seria leer todo el texto de golpe y meterlo en un array de caracteres, y luego vas recorriendo ese array de 100 en 100 posiciones.

Comment: Que pasa si la palabra que termina en ing esta en medio de dos bloques de 100 caracteres? (por ejemplo, 'i' es el ultimo de un bloque 'ng' son los primeros del siguiente bloque)

Comment: Tu código actual no lee bloques de 100 caracteres, lee lineas, y limita la longitud de la linea a 100 caracteres. Para leer 100 caracteres, podrías usar `getc()` en un ciclo que termine a los 100 caracteres o si encuentra _EOF_.